# Can't add new SQL database - error 26 - web developer 2010

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

My whole project is a Default.aspx and a web.config. When I go to add new item > SQL Server Database, I get this error:

[image]

I have looked around the internet for the past couple of hours and I just can't find anything (please keep in mind I am still a beginner so simple, detailed explanations are very welcome).

Comment: Can you list the name of the server and instance, and your connection string?

Answer (score 0):

This error means either:

a) You do not have Sql Server Express installed.

b) Sql Server is installed but isn't running, use Start -> View Local Services to start it up.

c) Sql Server is installed and running, but is not configured to allow connections. Use Start -> Sql server configuration manager to enable TCP/IP or named pipe connections.

d) Sql Server is installed and running and allows connections, but your firewall software is not configured to allow connections to Sql Server.

d) You have mistyped the Data Source value in your connection string, the default instance name for Sql Express is usually ".\SQLEXPRESS"

Configuration Tool Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How do i do option C? i opened up sql server configuration manager but how do i enable tcp/ip or named pipe connections?